# Proof: is the language $L_1=\{\langle M\rangle\mid\emptyset \subseteq L(M)\}$ (un)-decidable?

Tags: undecidability, decision-problem

I want to show that $L_1 = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \emptyset \subseteq L(M)\}$ is decidable/undecidable - without rice theorem (just for the case that I can apply it).

Every language contain the $\emptyset$ as a subset. So my guess is that the language is decidable.

Therefore, let us assume that $L_1$ is decidable. Lets say that $N$ is the TM which decides $L_1$.

N = "with input $<M>$:"

1. ...

How can I prove that $N$ is a decider for $L_1$?

Comment: 1. output "true".

Answer (score 2):

Your language $L_1 = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \emptyset \subseteq L(M)\}$ is trivially decidable by a Turing machine $T$ that just checks whether $\langle M \rangle$ is a valid description of a Turing Machine. If it is, $T$ accepts. Otherwise $T$ rejects.

Notice that, for any Turing machine $M$, $L(M)$ is a set (by definition) and therefore $\emptyset \subseteq L(M)$ is always true.

Answer (score 1):

$\emptyset$ Is the empty set symbol, not a valid string. Only valid strings may be contained in a language.

If you meant that $L(M) = \emptyset$ - It is not decidable: [ETM Undecidability](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53836/etm-undecidability)

If you meant that $L(M)$ contains the empty string - it is also not decidable. Suppose $D$ is a TM that decides it. Let $F$ be a function that, given $\langle M,w\rangle$, creates a Turing machine $M'$ that ignores its input and emulates $M$ on $w$ and accepts if $M$ accepts $w$. Now if $M$ accepts $w$ then $M'$ accepts every string, including the empty string, and accepts nothing. You would then be able to run $D$ on $\langle M'\rangle$ to decide if $M$ accepts $w$, a contradiction.

If you did mean your question literally, see this post - [Is the empty set in every language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464707/is-the-empty-set-in-every-language)